# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of null on my php document

Tags: javascript, php

I've been editing a survey to fit my project for my masters to collect data. I've gotten most of it to work however as I will show you below when the survey tries to reach the last 'slide' in which it submits the results to a another php file in order to collect the data I get the error above and it falls on this line of code:`document.getElementById("qu1_id").value = answer.join(",");`

FYI: I have tried console.log printing the variables of the answers and the survey seems to recognise the inputs.

Below is the code for the whole of the last slide including saving the answers and posting them to a separate php. In which the data is collected and made into a .csv file.
Apologies if this isn't the right format for the question. I'm a  psychology research student first time I have ever done any real coding. So I'm quite the novice.

```
    } else if (currSlide == 47) {
      checked = true;

        // Single array containing all answers
        var answer = [document.getElementById("nomem").value,nodes[0].q1,(nodes.length > 1) ? nodes[1].name : "", (nodes.length > 1) ? nodes[1].q2 : "",(nodes.length > 1) ? nodes[1].friendsWith : "",(nodes.length > 2) ? nodes[2].name : "",(nodes.length > 2) ? nodes[2].q2 : "",(nodes.length > 2) ? nodes[2].friendsWith : "",(nodes.length > 3) ? nodes[3].name : "",(nodes.length > 3) ? nodes[3].q2 : "",(nodes.length > 3) ? nodes[3].friendsWith : "",(nodes.length > 4) ? nodes[4].name : "",(nodes.length > 4) ? nodes[4].q2 : "",(nodes.length > 4) ? nodes[4].friendsWith : "",(nodes.length > 5) ? nodes[5].name : "",(nodes.length > 5) ? nodes[5].q2 : "",(nodes.length > 5) ? nodes[5].friendsWith : "",(nodes.length > 6) ? nodes[6].name : "",(nodes.length > 6) ? nodes[6].q2 : "",(nodes.length > 6) ? nodes[6].friendsWith : "",(nodes.length > 7) ? nodes[7].name : "",(nodes.length > 7) ? nodes[7].q2 : "",(nodes.length > 7) ? nodes[7].friendsWith : "",(nodes.length > 8) ? nodes[8].name : "",(nodes.length > 8) ? nodes[8].q2 : "",(nodes.length > 8) ? nodes[8].friendsWith : "",(nodes.length > 9) ? nodes[9].name : "",(nodes.length > 9) ? nodes[9].q2 : "",(nodes.length > 9) ? nodes[9].friendsWith : "",(nodes.length > 10) ? nodes[10].name : "",(nodes.length > 10) ? nodes[10].q2 : "",(nodes.length > 10) ? nodes[10].friendsWith : "",(nodes.length > 11) ? nodes[11].name : "",(nodes.length > 11) ? nodes[11].q2 : "",(nodes.length > 11) ? nodes[11].friendsWith : "",(nodes.length > 12) ? nodes[12].name : "",(nodes.length > 12) ? nodes[12].q2 : "",(nodes.length > 12) ? nodes[12].friendsWith : "",(nodes.length > 13) ? nodes[13].name : "",(nodes.length > 13) ? nodes[13].q2 : "",(nodes.length > 13) ? nodes[13].friendsWith : "",(nodes.length > 14) ? nodes[14].name : "",(nodes.length > 14) ? nodes[14].q2 : "",(nodes.length > 14) ? nodes[14].friendsWith : "",(nodes.length > 15) ? nodes[15].name : "",(nodes.length > 15) ? nodes[15].q2 : "",(nodes.length>15)?nodes[15].friendsWith:"",nodes[0].q5,nodes[0].q6,nodes[0].q7,nodes[0].q8,nodes[0].q9,nodes[0].q10,nodes[0].q11,nodes[0].q12,nodes[0].q13,nodes[0].q14,nodes[0].q15,nodes[0].q16,nodes[0].q17,nodes[0].q18,nodes[0].q19,nodes[0].q20,nodes[0].q21,nodes[0].q22,nodes[0].q23,nodes[0].q24,nodes[0].q25,nodes[0].q26,nodes[0].q27,nodes[0].q28,nodes[0].q29,nodes[0].q30,nodes[0].q31,nodes[0].q32,nodes[0].q33,nodes[0].q34,nodes[0].q35,nodes[0].q36,nodes[0].q37,nodes[0].q38,nodes[0].q39,nodes[0].q40];


        document.getElementById("qu1_id").value = answer.join(",");

        //Post collected data to handler for recording
        $.post( "save_results.php", {
        nomem: document.getElementById("nomem").value,
        q1: nodes[0].q1,
        q2_1: (nodes.length > 1) ? nodes[1].name : "",
        q3_1: (nodes.length > 1) ? nodes[1].q2 : "",
        q4_1: (nodes.length > 1) ? nodes[1].friendsWith : "",
        q2_2: (nodes.length > 2) ? nodes[2].name : "",
        q3_2: (nodes.length > 2) ? nodes[2].q2 : "",
        q4_2: (nodes.length > 2) ? nodes[2].friendsWith : "",
        q2_3: (nodes.length > 3) ? nodes[3].name : "",
        q3_3: (nodes.length > 3) ? nodes[3].q2 : "",
        q4_3: (nodes.length > 3) ? nodes[3].friendsWith : "",
        q2_4: (nodes.length > 4) ? nodes[4].name : "",
        q3_4: (nodes.length > 4) ? nodes[4].q2 : "",
        q4_4: (nodes.length > 4) ? nodes[4].friendsWith : "",
        q2_5: (nodes.length > 5) ? nodes[5].name : "",
        q3_5: (nodes.length > 5) ? nodes[5].q2 : "",
        q4_5: (nodes.length > 5) ? nodes[5].friendsWith : "",
        q2_6: (nodes.length > 6) ? nodes[6].name : "",
        q3_6: (nodes.length > 6) ? nodes[6].q2 : "",
        q4_6: (nodes.length > 6) ? nodes[6].friendsWith : "",
        q2_7: (nodes.length > 7) ? nodes[7].name : "",
        q3_7: (nodes.length > 7) ? nodes[7].q2 : "",
        q4_7: (nodes.length > 7) ? nodes[7].friendsWith : "",
        q2_8: (nodes.length > 8) ? nodes[8].name : "",
        q3_8: (nodes.length > 8) ? nodes[8].q2 : "",
        q4_8: (nodes.length > 8) ? nodes[8].friendsWith : "",
        q2_9: (nodes.length > 9) ? nodes[9].name : "",
        q3_9: (nodes.length > 9) ? nodes[9].q2 : "",
        q4_9: (nodes.length > 9) ? nodes[9].friendsWith : "",
        q2_10: (nodes.length > 10) ? nodes[10].name : "",
        q3_10: (nodes.length > 10) ? nodes[10].q2 : "",
        q4_10: (nodes.length > 10) ? nodes[10].friendsWith : "",
        q2_11: (nodes.length > 11) ? nodes[11].name : "",
        q3_11: (nodes.length > 11) ? nodes[11].q2 : "",
        q4_11: (nodes.length > 11) ? nodes[11].friendsWith : "",
        q2_12: (nodes.length > 12) ? nodes[12].name : "",
        q3_12: (nodes.length > 12) ? nodes[12].q2 : "",
        q4_12: (nodes.length > 12) ? nodes[12].friendsWith : "",
        q2_13: (nodes.length > 13) ? nodes[13].name : "",
        q3_13: (nodes.length > 13) ? nodes[13].q2 : "",
        q4_13: (nodes.length > 13) ? nodes[13].friendsWith : "",
        q2_14: (nodes.length > 14) ? nodes[14].name : "",
        q3_14: (nodes.length > 14) ? nodes[14].q2 : "",
        q4_14: (nodes.length > 14) ? nodes[14].friendsWith : "",
        q2_15: (nodes.length > 15) ? nodes[15].name : "",
        q3_15: (nodes.length > 15) ? nodes[15].q2 : "",
        q4_15: (nodes.length > 15) ? nodes[15].friendsWith : "",
        q5: nodes[0].q5,
        q6: nodes[0].q6,
        q7: nodes[0].q7,
        q8: nodes[0].q8,
        q9: nodes[0].q9,
        q10: nodes[0].q10,
        q11: nodes[0].q11,
        q12: nodes[0].q12,
        q13: nodes[0].q13,
        q14: nodes[0].q14,
        q15: nodes[0].q15,
        q16: nodes[0].q16,
        q17: nodes[0].q17,
        q18: nodes[0].q18,
        q19: nodes[0].q19,
        q20: nodes[0].q20,
        q21: nodes[0].q21,
        q22: nodes[0].q22,
        q23: nodes[0].q23,
        q24: nodes[0].q24,
        q25: nodes[0].q25,
        q26: nodes[0].q26,
        q27: nodes[0].q27,
        q28: nodes[0].q28,
        q29: nodes[0].q29,
        q30: nodes[0].q30,
        q31: nodes[0].q31,
        q32: nodes[0].q32,
        q33: nodes[0].q33,
        q34: nodes[0].q34,
        q35: nodes[0].q35,
        q36: nodes[0].q36,
        q37: nodes[0].q37,
        q38: nodes[0].q38,
        q39: nodes[0].q39,
        q40: nodes[0].q40
        });

        checked = false;


        var sf = document.getElementById("submitForm");
        var sb = document.getElementById("submitButton");
        var nd = document.getElementById("NextDiv");
        sf.style.display = "block";
        nd.style.display = "none";
        var motivationText = d3.select("svg").append("text")
          .attr("class", "slideText")
          .attr("id", "motivationText")
          .attr("x", center - (textWidth / 2) + 50)
          .attr("y", text_offset_top + 40)
          .text("Thank you for participating in this study. Click \"Next\" to end the survey.")
          .call(wrap, textWidth);

        // Release window close-prevention
        unhook();

      }

  }
```

Also this is the submit form in which the 'qu1_id' is referring to.

```
    <div id="submitForm">
  <form id="customapplication" action="<?php echo $_POST  ['returnpage']; ?>" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="sh" value="<?php echo $_POST['sh']; ?>"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="lsi" value="<?php echo $_POST['lsi']; ?>"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="pli" value="<?php echo $_POST['pli']; ?>"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="spi" value="<?php echo $_POST['spi']; ?>"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="aqi" value="<?php echo $_POST['aqi']; ?>"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="cqi" value="<?php echo $_POST['cqi']; ?>"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="KeyValue" value="<?php echo $_POST['KeyValue']; ?>"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="InterviewID" value="<?php echo $_POST['InterviewId']; ?>"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="Lmr" value="<?php echo $_POST['Lmr']; ?>"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="<?php echo $_POST['statusvarname1']; ?>" value="<?php echo $_POST['statusvarvalue1']; ?>"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="<?php echo $_POST['varname1']; ?>" id="qu1_id" value=""/>
    <input type="hidden" id="nomem" name="nomem" value="<?php echo $_POST['nomem']; ?>"/>
    <input name="<?php echo $_POST['nextvarname']; ?>" id="submitButton" class="btn btn-default" type="submit" value="Next"/>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript is throwing error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of null" yet element is present](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49271847/javascript-is-throwing-error-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-set-property-value-of)

Comment: @EugeneAnisiutkin Third input up from the bottom.

Comment: @cmprogram, Damn, I am blind =) didn't see that